# How to specify range in find() cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, range

I’m new to CakePHP and I’ve tried searching but I can’t find an answer to this question.

To put it simply, I want the query to be something like this:

```
SELECT id from posts WHERE id IN (15,18,20);
```

But I don’t know what to put in the `find()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the model it would be something like:

```
$ids   = array(15, 18, 20);
$posts = $this->find('all', array(
    'conditions'  => array(
        'Post.id' => $ids
     )
);
```

in the conditions array, you can pass an array of values to be used in the 'IN' clause

Comment: With default `recursive` level, specifying only `'id'` for the field name would probably fail if the model is linked to other models, because the field name would be ambiguous.

Comment: Agreed, I had posted just id in the SQL query for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: In your question I think it makes sense, but IMHO it had to be specified in the answer. This is what @dleiftah did with his update -> +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the CakePHP online manual at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions. Simply specify an array in your `conditions`:

```
<?php
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$results = $this->Post->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Post.id' => $ids
    )
));
```

Comment: I should have looked there. I tend to avoid the book because its quite confusing from time to time. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

From within the posts controller

```
$id_array = array(15, 18, 20);
$this->Post->find('all', array('Post.id' => $id_array));
```

More on the subject
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Answer (score -1):

`$conditions = array("Post.title" => array("First post", "Second post", "Third post"))
$this->find(all,array($conditions));`

Chk it if it works.